# Why one mesh is merge with array?

Tags: modifiers

I have just a default plane, scale down to make a rectangular shape. I have just array it with fit curve modifier. I have applied rotation scale to both curve and plane. All the mesh are equally distributed, In edit mode i can scale and adjusted it but. Why is a single mesh close / merge to each other.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion or help whats going wrong. Thanks

Comment: do you want all merged or all distributed?

Comment: @Chris distributed like others

Comment: @Chris is right.. the 'Fit to Curve' only adjusts the (integer) count of elements, to the maximum object-centers that can be fitted to the curve, given the scale, offset, etc. So you may have to fractionally scale the object in Edit Mode, change the offset, or change the length of the curve, to fit an exact number of [elememt + gap]s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change relative offset to 1.35.

Result:

[image]

Explanation:

What shall Blender do? It is mathematics. You give a circle (curve) with a radius. You give the width of one part. You give the offset.

If it doesn't fit - it doesn't fit. Blender can just overlap or leave a bigger gap. Blender cannot change mathematics. ;)

Comment: why playing with the count offset it fix not automatically

Comment: did you read and understand my explanation? below the picture?